# Free Phonegap OCR plugins for Android

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ocr

I'm trying to implement an Android Phonegap app but I cannot find a free OCR plugin. I want it to be a phonegap project so I can use the code later in an other platform.

What I could find was the OCRApiService phonegap plugin but it's not freeware.

Can anyone give me some info about this? Is there any other phonegap ocr plugin for android?

If this is not possible then how can I implement a normal java based android ocr plugin and use it in my phonegap project? Is it an easy process? If thats the case then later if I wish I would use an other OCR plugin for other platform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the best free engine is **Tesseract** which you can find how to implement it for android by searching for **Tesseract android fork**. But it's a little bit hard and of course with windows it's a kind of impossible.(You should install android NDK)

Another open source project is `javaOCR`. But it's so dependent on your training data.

---

**Edit**

Sorry for incomplete answer.
I think [this](https://github.com/jcesarmobile/PhonegapOCRPlugin) should be the one that you need for iOS.
And [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/OcrApiService) one for Android.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is can I implement Tesseract in a phonegap project?

Comment: I know tesseract can be used in an android project. But I'm implementing a Phonegap Android app. A phonegap app is based in html and javascript. It is easy to use tesseract in my app? Or is not possible?

Comment: Can I use jcesarmobile PhonegapOCRPlugin in an android phonegap project? I think this just works for iOS.

Comment: the answer is now EDITED.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already mentioned this OcrApiService in my original question. OcrApiService is not freeware, I need to sign up and the OCR is made in their servers. I need a offline plugin like tesseract that by the way works very well in XCode. But thanks anyway.

Comment: My plugin is just for iOS